# java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream reading gzip encoded website

Tags: java, gzip, compression, gzipinputstream

I am having trouble with the compression of some websites. The following code should work fine, but throws an `EOFException`. All major browsers can load the site and I also have no problem using curl with gzip.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.ddanzi.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    System.out.println("Encoding: " + connection.getContentEncoding());
    System.out.println("Bytes: " + IOUtils.toByteArray(new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream())).length);
}
```

This will be the output:

```
Encoding: gzip
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:462)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
```

And this is not the only website I have problems with gzip encoding. I also have problems with

- mgtv.com
- yxdown.com
- weather.com.cn
- ebrun.com

Am I doing something wrong?

My system is Win7 x64, Java 8 Update 102.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I could just read the stream by myself and swallow the exception, but at the moment the exception occurs, I could loose *bufferSize* bytes and have a corrupt/incomplete document. Is there a way to get over this issue (except to set *bufferSize* to 1)?

**Edit 2:** As a workaround to get the bytes till the exception occurs, one could e.g. read the stream like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream():
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    while(true) {
        int read = inputStream.read(buffer);
        if (read == -1) break;
        baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}catch(Exception e) {
    // Just swallow or Log or something...
}
byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
```

But the problem here is, how to choose *bufferSize*? When it is e.g. set to 1000 and at some point like when reading the last of the current 1000 bytes the exception occurs, I will lost all the correctly read 999 bytes right before. The perfect value for completeness would be 1, but that is VERY SLOW.

So, how to get all correct readable data without loosing performance?

Comment: Are you at least able to read a few lines ? If you are, it means they're not returning gzipped data, although I would expect the error message to be `Not in GZIP format`

Comment: If I read manually with a buffer I can see that it is reading till the end and then throws this exception... I could swallow it and just could use the bytes that were read, but the document may not be complete then

Comment: By the way the name of all of these sites seem suspicious dude...

Comment: A bit a googling tells me that `yxdown.exe` and `Ebrun.exe` are two known malwares targeting Windows. Didn't find anything for the other ones but it does not mean they're safe either

Comment: I am iterating over the top one million domains from alexa: http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip

Comment: Then I would be careful not to download anything from random domains

Comment: For the first step, I just want to retrieve the html documents, best complete and without any errors... Because the user may enter any website later, it should work with every website.

Comment: It can't work with every website unless every website (a) works and (b) produces GZipped output. I don't see any reason to believe either. Why are you assuming GZip? I don't understand what you think `bufferSize` has to do with it either.

Comment: @EJP As long as the website is working fine in the browser, it should also work in my program. And the code is just a short snippet to show the error, I am aware of the fact, that the server may send data not in gzip encoding. Concerning *bufferSize*, please have a look at my second edit.

Comment: No. The browser take notice of the Content-encoding header. The code you posted doesn't. If that isn't the real code, posting it was futile. NB There is no issue about choosing `bufferSize`. Any size from 1 upwards will work, as long as you can allocate it. This is a red herring. You only have to decide how accurate your answer needs to be, and nobody else can help with that. And you don't need to accumulate all the data: just *count* it.

Comment: If I post the complete code, I would scare all those helpful people, so I just extracted the interesting part out of it. But if you need more source code that will be no problem. Just have a look at [jsoup](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup)...

Back to topic: No, if I choose bufferSize to be 1000, but e.g. the stream only contains 900 and is corrupted, then I will have nothing at the end. And 899 bytes would be better than zero bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are seeing that exception is that the server is responding incorrectly. Try `http://www.google.com` instead and you'll see that your code works (You may get a 302 response, just follow the redirection).

What you can do is to make your code more robust. Keep in mind that the server can and will respond anything. For example, you may have asked for `gzip` encoding, but the server may choose to return plain text. And the code need to deal with such situations.

Comment: I know that the server may respond in any way (with or without gzip encoding). It was just a short snippet I created to show the misery. And as long as the browser can parse it, my program should as well...

Comment: I believe for the broken web sites you have to fall back to "identity" encoding. That's probably what browsers are doing behind the scene.

Comment: The problem is, that the data is indeed gzip encoded. Just, as you say, the server responds incorrectly. But nevertheless, I need all the bytes I could get.

Comment: I mean. It's broken gzip data you cannot decode. But in the end it's the content that matters, not the means to transmit the content. For those broken web sites, you just cannot use gzip in the request. But you can always ask for plain text.

Comment: Ok, that would work here... A simple and straight forward solution. But that would mean I have to do a second request. I was hoping for a way to analyze the readable data and if the interesting part is present, just ignore the error and do not do a second request ;)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason some sites from the list returning truncated `gzip` content. You can verify it manually using `curl`

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://www.ebrun.com/ 2>/dev/null \
  | zcat >/dev/null 
gzip: skipping: <stdin>: corrupted -- missing trailer
```

So your code is valid. You should blame websites.

Comment: His code isn't valid. He should check the returned content-encoding before assuming it is GZipped.

Comment: @EJP well... Code of course need improvements, but it is generally a more or less proper way to read gzipped data. In case of `http://www.ebrun.com` the `Content-Encoding` is `gzip` but stream is corrupted.

Comment: @vsminkov: I was expecting that. Do you know any workaround?